# Can't use lightning components in create-lwc-app

Tags: lightning-web-components

I created create-lwc-app (with Electron) and the build breaks when I try to use lightning-textarea for example (Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lightning/textarea' in .....').

Are those not supported at all? Or am I missing additional configurations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Lightning Components (everything in the lightning namespace) are closed source and do not come with LWC (in fact, LWC doesn't come with *any* components at all!). If you want to build your own, you are free to use SLDS to recreate those elements, but you'll have to do it yourself. Also, the @wire method is automatically generated in Salesforce, but outside of Salesforce, you also have to implement your own wire methods.